# MongoDB with Eclipse not throwing exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoDB with Eclipse in a very basic way, but can't get it working properly!

My code looks like the following (JavaSE-1.6 and mongo-java-drive-2.12.0-rc0.jar):

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MongoDBProjects {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
         MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "xyz" , 123);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

This code doesn't show any error in the Eclipse console, but the code should throw an UnknowHostException, because no mongoDB instance is running on xyz and listening on port 123!

Why is that?

Regards,
Gerard

Comment: Are you sure you're running this class, but not some other ?

Comment: Yes, when I add for example the following line `<String> tables = db.getCollectionNames();` to my code I get the exception: MongoServerSelectionException!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoClient doesn't create a persistent network connection. It creates a connection when it needs one and closes it again when it doesn't. You won't get a network error message before you actually attempt to do something with a database.

The first thing you will usually do in a real-world application after creating a MongoClient is get a database and [authenticate](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/DB.html#authenticate%28java.lang.String,%20char%5B%5D%29) to it. That's the first time you will notice when MongoDB is offline.

Comment: Can't I force it to create a persistent connection?

Comment: Authentication is the next thing I want to test! Thanks for taking the trouble to answer this question!

Comment: @g.verhaag You have no control over individual connections. The MongoClient uses connection-pooling (when you make lots of queries at the same time, it automatically uses and reuses multiple connections in parallel). The connection-handling functionality is completely hidden from the application developer.